# We have both electric-propulsion and ion-thruster tags, are they distinct? What would be good usage guidance for electric-propulsion?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

The [ion-thruster](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ion-thruster) tag is used on 125 questions and it's usage guidance is:

> Questions about engines used in space that accelerate ions to create thrust.

and it has been synonymized with [ion-drive](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ion-drive), [ion-engine](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ion-engine) and [ion-propulsion](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ion-propulsion).

The [electric-propulsion](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-propulsion) tag is on 59 questions, and it's usage guidance is:

> The electric-propulsion tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

**Question:** Is [electric-propulsion](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-propulsion) a catch-all tag for several kinds of propulsion that may not overlap with [ion-thruster](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ion-thruster)? Perhaps things that use charged particles in the solar wind or existing magnetic fields along with electrical power in a spacecraft? Or should these two also be synonymized?

Comment: Resistojets are electric propulsion devices that are not ion-thrusters. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistojet_rocket

Comment: @OrganicMarble  To "Is electric-propulsion a catch-all tag for several kinds of propulsion that may not overlap with ion-thruster?" are you suggesting "yes" without saying it? [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20417/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/35297/12102) (and [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qT9HBkWGg7s&t=95s) from [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35958/12102)) are also "electro-thermal" as well. Should questions like those first two have the `electro-propulsion` tag as well?

Comment: I'm agreeing (I think) that "electric propulsion" =/= "ion-thruster"

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'm currently un-coffee'd so you have me at an advantage. I see, to "...are they distinct" the answer is yes.

Comment: There are enough questions between the two tags to justify having more than one tag.  However, I do not feel qualified to specify exactly *what* those tags should be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments under the question it seems that the two tags are indeed distinct and refer to different methods, capabilities and equipment.

Before going further, let's see what all "electric propulsion" can mean to the community. I've just asked [What are all the kinds of electric propulsion that don't qualify as ion propulsion in standard spaceflight lingo?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51812/12102) and included a list of potentially relevant questions here that may at least partially "[span the space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span)" so to speak.